# How to get database backup on running website on click of a button using asp.net

Tags: database, backup

Code which I m using for button

```
protected void btn_backup_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            Class_Backup objbackup = new Class_Backup();
            objbackup.BackUpPath = "SalvageManager" + DateTime.Now.ToString().Replace("/", "_").Replace(":", "_").Replace("-","_").Replace(" ","_");
            objbackup.BackupData();
            if (objbackup.OperationStatus != false)
            {

            Response.ContentType = "application/bak";
            Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + objbackup.BackUpPath);
            Response.TransmitFile(Server.MapPath("~/DataBaseBackUp/" + objbackup.BackUpPath));
            Response.End();
            //Response.Redirect(Server.MapPath("~/DataBaseBackUp/" + objbackup.BackUpPath),false);
        }
        else
        {
            lbl_message.Text = objbackup.ErrorMessage;
        }

    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        lbl_message.Text = ex.Message;
    }
}
```

When I click on button following error occured

> Error : Cannot open backup device 'D:\INETPUB\VHOSTS\salvagemanagers.com\httpdocs\DataBaseBackUp\SalvageManager8_19_2013_12_18_01_PM'. Operating system error 3(The system cannot find the path specified.). BACKUP DATABASE is terminating abnormally.

Comment: Please post the source  for  `Class_Backup`.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure the path exists in your database server and not on your client machine.